# Collections.min dont return the min value in Java Android

Tags: java, android, collections

Im writing an android app in Java and I want to get the minimum value from hmButtonsValue.
The thing is that sometimes selectedButtonValue  acctualy get the minimum value, but other times it get the second minimum value.
Why does it happen and how can I fix that?

```
private HashMap<Integer, String> hmButtonsValues;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    hmButtonsValues = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
}

public void someFunc(){
    ...
    hmButtonsValues.put(buttonsArr[i].getId(), buttonsArr[i].getText()
                .toString());
}
// Here is where selectedButtonValue get its min value
selectedButtonValue = Integer.parseInt(Collections.min(hmButtonsValues
            .values()));
```

The values in buttonsArr are fine, I generate them randomly and set the buttons text to display them. So I guess the problem is with the Collections.min function, but I dont know what it is.

Comment: You are aware that you are using min on String values? Thus don't expect it to be in the same order as it would be if the Strings were Integers

Comment: OK my code is a real mess and I got confused.. 
Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't think about that deeply enough.
Anyway it works now, thanks!